Проблемы с языком Julia при установке программы
Я пытаюсь установить программу https://github.com/balashev/spectro?tab=readme-ov-file
Однако при установке возникают следующие ошибки:
ImportError: <PyCall.jlwrap (in a Julia function called from Python)
JULIA: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package DataStructures not found in current path.
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("DataStructures")` to install the DataStructures package.

Написано, что нужно запустить import Pkg; Pkg.add("DataStructures"), но я не понимаю, где это нужно сделать.
Как вылечить эти ошибки?
